# Batch/cmd how to copy name specific files?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy

I am trying to copy pdf files which are named with `KBSMPP*.pdf`, just like in Linux. The file also could have more strings, but it is stil a pdf, e.g. `KBSMPP_____.pdf`

I have many Files, the files are named:

```
KBSMPP1.pdf
KBSMPP345.pdf
KBSMPPKL.pdf
```

I don't know how it works. How can I search specific name files?

My code in Batch is:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\Manfred\Documents\KBSMPP*.pdf" "H:\Users\Hendrik\Documents\Frames"
```

Another example which I have tried:

```
ROBOCOPY "C:\Users\Manfred\Documents\KBSMPP*.*pdf" H:\Users\Hendrik\Documents\Frames "KBSMPP*.pdf"
```

Comment: What is your issue? (what do you get and how does it differ from what you want?). Btw: `robocopy` has a different syntax. See `robocopy /?`

Comment: i edit it. Hopefuly you can understand it better.

Comment: What is the problems you experience with the current code?

Comment: The current problem is i dont know how to copy many files which are named with ```KBSMPP```to the other device. I just want the files, which are started with the label ```KBSMPP*```. These files ```KBSMPP1.pdf
KBSMPP345.pdf
KBSMPPKL.pdf.```

Comment: ok, so what happened when you tried running the examples you gave?

Comment: For The Robocopy ``` Error invalid Parameters "C:\Users\Manfred\Documents\KBSMPP*.*pdf" ```

Comment: Yes, because you used it wrong, what happened when you ran the first `xopy` command in your example?

Comment: Please also note, _based upon your provided paths_, you may not be running with sufficient privileges to copy from a location within another users profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several methods.

Using Copy:

```
Copy "C:\Users\Manfred\Documents\KBSMPP*.pdf" "H:\Users\Hendrik\Documents\Frames\"
```

Using Robocopy:

```
ROBOCOPY "C:\Users\Manfred\Documents" "H:\Users\Hendrik\Documents\Frames" KBSMPP*.pdf /MT:32 /B
```

Using a `FOR` Loop you can paste into a cmd prompt:

```
FOR %A IN ( "C:\Users\Manfred\Documents\KBSMPP*.pdf") DO (
  COPY "%fa" "H:\Users\Hendrik\Documents\Frames\" )
```

Comment: Thank you every one. Now it works it was the Problem of the Syntax.

Comment: I have another Question, it is an another file type. But this dont works with the same as for the ```pdf``` . This file type is ```.CATDrawing``` i just want to copy 18 files to another device.

Comment: @H4rdJ3ash, to learn how to use the `cmd.exe` built-in `copy` command, open a Command Prompt window, type `copy /?`, and press enter; all the information you need is in there. As long as you've not removed important entries from `%PATH%` and/or `%PATHEXT%`, you should be able to repeat the process with `Robocopy /?` and `xcopy /?`. If there's a chance that those variables have been modified, it may be safer to use, `"%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" /?`, and `"%__AppDir__%xcopy.exe" /?`.